# help understanding ba5954fp sled motor driver application circuit from datasheet

Tags: motor, integrated-circuit, driver, stepper-motor, datasheet

i'm trying to drive a sled motor (bipolar, 4 wires) using the IC BA595FP
i found in the datasheet this application circuit:
[image]

i'm not very familiar with the terminologie of datasheets, so i have the following questions:

1- My stepper motor is 4 wires but there is only two pins in this ship for the sled motor, it's PIN 11 and 12 ? where should i connect the other two wires of the motor ?

2- What does μ-COM in the left upper rectangle mean ? StandBy, LOADING ?

3- Concerning the first rectangle, does DSP mean the source of PWM signal used to control the sled motor ?

*any sources are welcome,
Thank you

datasheet : [BA595FP](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Rohm%20PDFs/ba5954fp-e.pdf)

Comment: "Sled" may translate in English to "stepper" . IF SO that's what you should use. Otherwise - WHAT IS a "sled"

Comment: ah ok, @RussellMcMahon thank you for clarifying that, the motor used to move the laser in a cd rom reader is called sled motor, anyway it's a stepper motor

Comment: Always a good idea to provide links where available eg [**BA5954FP data sheet here**](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Rohm%20PDFs/ba5954fp-e.pdf)  - and anything else of likely use.

Comment: I don't think this is designed to drive stepper motors. It is for 2-wire permanent magnet DC motors with brushes.

Comment: i think what you said is very possible

Comment: Sled motors are usually brushed DC motors, the application doesn't usually call for the accurate positioning of steppers. "Loading" is the motor that extends and retracts te CD/DVD tray